# Get_Header not working on Home Page Wordpress - Tried Almost Everything

Tags: php, html, wordpress

At my website: www.TattiniBoots.com, I would like to add a larger header than what exists on all other pages. Below is the code that I am using

```
<?php 
       if (is_front_page() ) {
               get_header( 'home' );

        } else {
               wp_head();
       }
?>
```

When removing the else function, all other pages lose the header except the home page; and therefore I am sure that the call script is working appropriately

My new header file that I am calling is: "header-home.php" which includes the col-md-12 instead of col-md-3. However, it does not display

Even when removing all code inside "header-home.php" the original old header will still display on the home page

What am I doing wrong?

I simply need one line of code to be altered on this index page (col-md-12 instead of col-md-3)

Comment: What file is this code in?

Comment: This code is in the file: Head.php

Comment: Have you created the file "header-home.php" in your WordPress child theme directory?

Comment: All of this is in the parent theme. But yes I have created header-home.php in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this programmatically without having to create a different header-home.php. Following is the code.

```
if (is_front_page()){
 $header_home_class = "col-md-12";
} else {
 $header_home_class = "col-md-3";
}
```

//whereever you want to add the class name

```
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr($header_home_class);?>">
```

Comment: Except I am using WordPress. Therefore I am not sure which file to actually put this into

Comment: You can add this code in header.php itself inside PHP tag and fetch the $header_home_class in the div or section you would like to.

Comment: However it just breaks the site and does not get past the loader. Did I do something wrong? This is in the header.php file

Comment: turn the debug mode on, wp-config.php search for (DEBUG, false) and change it to true, there must be an error in the file.

Comment: if in case that you are not using WordPress then there should be other inbuilt function to check the frontpage of the website. is_front_page() is supposed to be used with WordPress only.

Comment: I am using Wordpress. There were no errors in the file